# Create multicolumn, vertically sorted, aligned, evenly-sized list items with CSS for an unknown number of items

Tags: css

I'm trying to do something that feels like it shouldn't be hard, but I'm having a hard time finding the right fit.

Essentially, I have a list of items, but I don't know how many I'll receive. I want to display them in 2 columns, sorted vertically (meaning, the first column contains the first half of the list).

If my list looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

Then I want to achieve a layout like this:

```
| a | e 
| b | f
| c | g
| d
```

Because the number of items is unknown, I cannot set a fixed height on the list.

Using `column-count` gets me quite close, with one problem: If the text in any of the list items wraps to second line, the alignment breaks. Unfortunately, I cannot control the text length within each list item and expect it will wrap sometimes.

I've also tried various approaches using `display:grid` with no success.

Comment: Column count is clearly the appropriate method barring javascript but the real issue is the alignment. Unfortunately I don't believe there is a simple CSS method of solving the problem.